# Interaction term vs subgroup analysis

Tags: regression, interaction

**I have a question regarding the choice between interaction term and subgroup analysis.**

Suppose that I want to study the association between education and income by sex. I can fit a model with an interaction term as: `income = education*sex`

Or, fit a simpler model among males and females separately: `income = education`

In both analyses, I am interested in the point estimate (odds ratio) and 95% confidence interval. Below is an hypothetical example. In this example, statistical testing about whether the association differs by sex is ***not*** the outcome of interest. Both analyses generated the same results.

However, I got a vague impression that it is generally recommended to add interaction term rather than conducting subgroup analyses.

- If this is TRUE, it is unclear about the reasons underlying this recommendation, since both methods have the same results.
- If this is FALSE, does it mean that the two approaches are equal in terms of obtaining the point estimate and confidence interval?

**Any comments would be much appreciated!**

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)

n <- 1000 
sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, replace = TRUE)  
education <- sample(c("Low", "High"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))  

income <- ifelse(education == "Low", 
                 sample(c("Low", "High"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.25)),
                 sample(c("Low", "High"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.25, 0.75)))  

data <- data.frame(sex = as.factor(sex), education = factor(education, levels = c("Low", "High")), income = factor(income, levels = c("Low", "High")))
summary(data)


### Logistic regression: Overall ###
# among females
model_overall <- glm(income ~ education*sex, data = data, family = "binomial")
round( exp( coef(model_overall)["educationHigh"] ), 2 ) # 8.69
round( exp( confint(model_overall)["educationHigh", ] ), 2 ) # 5.84-13.09

# among males
data$sex <- relevel( data$sex, ref = "Male" )
model_overall <- glm(income ~ education*sex, data = data, family = "binomial")
round( exp( coef(model_overall)["educationHigh"] ), 2 ) # 6.97
round( exp( confint(model_overall)["educationHigh", ] ), 2 ) # 4.73-10.40

### subgroup analyses ###
# Logistic regression: female subgroup
model_female <- glm(income ~ education, data = filter(data, sex == "Female"), family = "binomial")
round( exp( coef(model_female)["educationHigh"] ), 2 ) # 8.69
round( exp( confint(model_female)["educationHigh", ] ), 2 ) # 5.84-13.09

# Logistic regression: Male subgroup
model_male <- glm(income ~ education, data = filter(data, sex == "Male"), family = "binomial")
round( exp( coef(model_male)["educationHigh"] ), 2 ) # 6.97
round( exp( confint(model_male)["educationHigh", ] ), 2 ) # 4.73-10.40
```

Answer (score 8):

There are many reasons why careful interaction modeling should almost always be done instead of subgroup analysis, including

- Subgrouping does not carry along the very good covariate adjustment you get from the full model
- For many models, such as linear regression, subgrouping creates inefficient estimates of auxiliary parameters such as $\sigma^2$
- Subgroup estimates are misleading because you can’t do things like comparing overlap of confidence intervals across subgroups (a common mistake) and you can’t compare p-values across subgroups (another comment mistake, e.g., concluding a treatment works in one subgroup and not another when p=0.02 and 0.050001)
- Subgroup estimates do not allow for correction for overfitting that a unified analysis handles through random effects for the group x covariate interaction effects
- It is illegal (or should be) to create subgroups from non-nominal (categorical) covariates.  For example, though one frequently sees subgroups formed from intervals of age, this is improper and will result in residual confounding and impossibility of having a definite interpretation of the result.
- Interaction assessment provides a formal way to build evidence for differential effects.
- Subgrouping on one variable is in effect allowing that variable to interact with all the other variables, which is inefficient, because estimation is done independently in each subgroup.

Comment: The last point is particularly helpful to me: "Subgrouping on one variable is in effect allowing that variable to interact with all the other variables, which is inefficient, because estimation is done independently in each subgroup." Many thanks!